# How to align text inside Positioned widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to align the text in bottom left inside a LinearGradient container, as in the image, but as I am placing the column widget as a child of a container, it gets placed in the center. So, whats the correct code I need to edit for the result in the image.

[image]
[image]

main.dart

```
SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      width: 300,
                      height: 220,
                      child: Stack(
                        fit: StackFit.expand,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Image(
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            image: AssetImage('assets/image1.png'),
                          ),
                          Positioned(
                            left: 0,
                            bottom: 0,
                            child: Container(
                              width: 285,
                              height: 110,
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left:8, bottom: 30),
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                                    begin: FractionalOffset.center,
                                    end: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
                                    colors: [
                                      const Color(0XFF000000).withOpacity(.0),
                                      const Color(0XFF000000).withOpacity(0.8),
                                    ],
                                  )
                              ),
                              child: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Text(
                                    "Jerusalem",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontFamily: 'AirbnbCerealBold',
                                        fontSize: 28,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    "1,243 Place",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontFamily: 'AirbnbCerealBook',
                                        fontSize: 14,
                                        color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried with the

> mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,

with the Column

```
child: Column(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
```

It works.